# What does binding mean?

Tags: macroeconomics, optimization

I am curious how to solve the utility maximization problem if the representative agent has borrowing constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraint $g(x)\geq 0$ is binding if in optimum $g(x) = 0$ rather than the constraint being slack $g(x)>0$.

Comment: Thank you. How can I solve the problem with such an inequality constraint, like, a' > a_bar?

Comment: You can make a new question here on the site to get help. Standard procedure is to use Lagrange.